# How to pass data to google-maps callback functions and prevent memory leaks

Tags: api, events, google-maps

I am working with a vast of markers 10.000+ and all of them should be clickable. At the moment I create a separate callback function for each marker, which is a closure over all the data I need. I have tried to prevent the creation of 10.000 functions, which do all the same and pass the data I need as an argument to the cb-function, but this seems impossible.

But there is a way to get the data to the callback function anyway. 'This' points, int the cb-function, to the actual clicked marker and I can access the required data, if I attach them to the marker object. This is very dirty but it seems to work.

But this causes further problems: I doubt this causes memory leaks. I reference the marker in the Object which the marker stands for like obj.marker but to access the object in the cb-function I have to reference the object like marker.obj

```
// Callback function for clicks on markers
function cb(e){
    console.log(e); // the event with information about marker position
    console.log(this.obj); // the object the marker stands for
}

//add a eventListener to the marker which represents a object
this.initMarkerListener = function(obj) {
    obj.marker.obj = obj;     //the critical point
    google.maps.event.addListener(obj.marker, 'click', cb);
};
```

Does this creates a memory leak? And can I pass the required data with a other technique to the callback function?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with the approach you've taken. A memory leak occurs when references that you expect to 'clean up' (let the GB clean up unused references) are left behind.

Consider then, that if marker exists in memory, and you delete obj, because marker holds a reference to obj, then the GB will not pick obj up to free up that memory part.